# Lay image over text in HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to have several images where when the user hovers over each one, the image disappears, revealing text underneath.  Right now, the image disappears when hovering but text remains above the image at all times.

HTML

```
<table align="center" style="width: 90vw;margin-right: 10vw;margin-left: 10vw;">

    <tr>
        <th>
            <div class="inhabitantOne">
                <p>Test Text.  Test Text.  Test Text.  Test Text.</p>
                <img src="judas.jpg">
            </div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div class="inhabitantTwo">
                <img src="cain.jpg">
            </div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div class="inhabitantThree">
                <img src="Ganelon.jpg">
            </div>
        </th>
    </tr>
```

CSS

```
.inhabitantOne {
  background-color: #8592b2;
  border-radius: 2vw;
  height: 20vw;
  width: 20vw;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #505151;
}

.inhabitantOne img {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}


.inhabitantOne:hover img {
  opacity: 0.0;
}
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can add a class to the <p> tag and initially add the CSS display to none and on hover change the display to block like you have done for the img.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css

```
p{
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
p:hover{
  text-indent: 0%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

or if you want to be specific for each div class use this:

```
.inhabitantOne p{

  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inhabitantOne p:hover{
  text-indent: 0%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added a common class to all of the divs

```
    <tr>
        <th>
            <div class="inhabitant inhabitantOne">
                <p>Test Text.  Test Text.  Test Text.  Test Text.</p>
                <img src="judas.jpg">
            </div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div class="inhabitant inhabitantTwo">
                <img src="cain.jpg">
            </div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div class="inhabitant inhabitantThree">
                <img src="Ganelon.jpg">
            </div>
        </th>
    </tr>
```

Just add these to your css

```
.inhabitant p {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.inhabitant:hover p{
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.inhabitant:hover img{
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

If you want nice smooth transition you can add to .inhabitant p class

```
transition: all .2s
```